# Return only 1 record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 2 tables, which look like this:

**Table 1**: `personal`

```
| uid      |      city     |
|----------|:-------------:|
| 1        |  Zurich       |
| 2        |  Chicago      |
| 3        |  London       |
```

**Table 2**: `technologies`

```
| uid      |      tech     |
|----------|:-------------:|
| 2        |  HTML         |
| 2        |  JavaScript   |
| 2        |  PHP          |
```

**The query that I use:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT personal.city, technologies.tech
FROM personal
INNER JOIN technologies
ON personal.uid = 2
```

**The result:**

```
| Chicago      |  HTML         |
| Chicago      |  JavaScript   |
| Chicago      |  PHP          |
```

As you see, I receive 3 records. My goal is to receive only 1 record. So the strings (HTML, JavaScript, PHP) should be either in an array (if that's possible) or they should be separated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like this:

```
SELECT personal.city, GROUP_CONCAT(technologies.tech)
FROM personalINNER JOIN technologies 
ON technologies.uid = personal.uid
WHERE personal.uid = 2
GROUP BY personal.city
```

You can also set the order of the items by:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(technologies.tech ORDER BY technologies.tech)
```

or choose another column for the order.

Answer (score 1):

The `DISTINCT` keyword always applies to *all* the columns in your select-list, not just the single column following the `DISTINCT` keyword. It did what it is designed to do, it returned enough rows so that no row has the same set of values as another row.

If you want one row for Chicago, basically to do a `DISTINCT` on one column, use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT personal.city, ...what goes here?
FROM personal
INNER JOIN technologies
ON personal.uid = 2
GROUP BY personal.city
```

MySQL has a function `GROUP_CONCAT()` to append multiple values together as it collapses multiple rows from a group into one row.

```
SELECT personal.city, GROUP_CONCAT(technologies.tech) AS list_of_tech
FROM personal
INNER JOIN technologies
ON personal.uid = 2
GROUP BY personal.city;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for details. There are options for changing the separator between the values, or sorting the values, or eliminating duplicates.